# Not add or remove, but edit a combobox item in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, combobox

So I have this combobox, which ItemsSource is set to a List of objects.

What I want to do after that is change the Display value of one specific Item (the first on the list), because this label does not suit the context in some situations but does in others.

So far I found that you could **add** an item using the **Add** method, **insert** one using the **Insert** method, and **remove** one using **RemoveAt**.

But how do you **update** one ? I know I could use RemoveAt and Insert afterwards, but it would be a bit labor intensive, plus I would have to recreate the object with all its values...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either *replace* an item in your "List of objects":

```
myList[0] = new MyObject("Another display text").
```

For this (and `Add`, `Remove` etc) to work, your list would have to be an `ObservableCollection<T>` or any other that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Or *modify* the item itself:

```
myList[0].DisplayText = "Another display text";
```

For this to work, your `MyObject` class would have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you'd have to raise the `PropertyChanged` event when the `DisplayText` property is set, and you'd have to set the `DisplayMemberPath` or the `ItemTemplate` of your `ComboBox` correctly.

Take a look at the [MVVM pattern](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mvvm) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. It was indeed simpler to just change the object list before assigning it as the combobox's ItemsSource